# ValueError: time data '2017-04-20 10:00:00-04:00' does not match format '%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S-%Z'

Tags: python, strftime

```
ValueError: time data '2017-04-20 10:00:00-04:00' does not match format '%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S-%Z'
```

I'm confused with the timezone part

Comment: The timezone needs to be `0400` with a plus or minus on it. The minus isn't separate, it's included, but there definitely shouldn't be a colon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%b` token is for an *abbreviated month name*. `04` isn't a name. `%b` expects something more like `Apr`. For a numeric month, use `%m`.

Comment: Also wrong on the timezone, I think. `04:00` doesn't look right